# How to take multiple inputs and get a final value if all are true?

Tags: javascript, html

Probably easier to explain here than my title. I have 3 inputs for a user, if all three meet my conditions, then I want to write something to the HTML, if all three do not meet the conditions, then I want a different phrase written to HTML. The issue I'm having is getting all 3 inputs to meet my conditions, I know I can use an if else statement for the writing of the HTML after each one is true or not. I need the GPA input to be greater than 2.75, student group input to be >=1 and the SUNY student one just has to be a yes or a no, yes for the condition to be true.(Not sure how to format that input so you can only choose yes or no, like a drop down box or something)

```
<form>
  Do you qualify to join the club?<br>
  Your GPA:<br> 
  <input type="number"><br>
  How many student groups do you belong to?<br> 
  <input type="number"><br>
  Are you a SUNY student?<br> 
  <input type="text">
</form>
<button type="submit" onclick:"qualify()">See if you qualify</button>
</form>
<h4 id="qual"> Look here to check</h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't mind including JQuery, you could use the following method. I've added a `<select>` menu for your Yes/No dropdown, and removed the `<form>` element, as using front-end validation doesn't require it. Here's a [working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atLgb9jb/) and the code is below.

**The HTML**

```
    Do you qualify to join the club?
    <br>
    Your GPA:<br> <input type="number" id="gpa">
    <br>
    How many student groups do you belong to?<br> <input type="number" id="sg">
    <br>
    Are you a SUNY student?<br>
    <select id="suny">
       <option value="">Choose...</option>
       <option value="yes">Yes</option>
       <option value="no">No</option>
    </select>
    <button id="btnQualify">See if you qualify</button>
    <h4 id="qual"> Look here to check</h4>
```

---

**The JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() { //when the page loads
   $("#btnQualify").click(function() { //when the btn is clicked
      var $gpa = $("#gpa");
      var $sg = $("#sg");
      var $suny = $("#suny");

      //parseInt is used to convert text to a number for comparison
      if (parseInt($gpa.val()) > 2.75 && parseInt($sg.val()) >= 1 && $suny.val() == "yes") {
           //All true, set h4
           $("#qual").html("You met all conditions!");
      } else {
           //Not all true, set h4
           $("#qual").html("You did not meet all conditions.");
      }
   });
 });
```

PS: SUNY alum represent!

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention what you want to write to the html.
I have changed the markup because with button submit form gets reloaded, not sure if you want that behaviour

You can check the following code snippet, to achieve what you have explained

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#qualify").bind('click',function(){
    
      var gpa=$("#GPA").val();
    gpa=gpa-0;
    var students=$("#students").val();
    students=students-0;
    var studentType=$("#studenttype").val();

    if(gpa>=2.75 && students>1 && studentType=="Yes")
        alert("successful");
      
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
                Do you qualify to join the club?
                <br>
                Your GPA:<br> <input type="number" id="GPA">
                <br>
                How many student groups do you belong to?<br> <input type="number" id="students">
                <br>
                Are you a SUNY student?<br> <input type="text" id="studenttype">
                </form>
                <input type="button" id="qualify" value="See if you qualify"/>
                </form>
                <h4 id="qual"> Look here to check</h4>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
                            You could do something like this:

var firstInput = document.getElementByTagName("input")[0];
var secondInput = document.getElementByTagName("input")[1];
var thirdInput = document.getElementByTagName("input")[2];
if((firstInput > 2.75) && (secondInput >= 1) && (thirdInput == "yes") || (thirdInput == "no")){document.write("<b>YOUR CONTENT HERE</b>")}
else{document.write("<b>YOUR CONTENT HERE</b>")}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way using plain javascript.

It would need you to really flesh out better validation but it works as a nice starting point:

```js
function qualify() {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var result = 'Not Qualified!';
  // crude and without much validation here:
  if (inputs[0].value > 2.75 && inputs[1].value >= 1 && ['yes', 'Yes'].indexOf(inputs[2].value) > -1) {
    result = 'Qualified!';
  }
  document.getElementById('qual').innerHTML = result;
};
window.qualify = qualify;
```

```html
<form>
  Do you qualify to join the club?
  <br> Your GPA:
  <br>
  <input type="number">
  <br> How many student groups do you belong to?
  <br>
  <input type="number">
  <br> Are you a SUNY student?
  <br>
  <input type="text">
</form>
<button type="submit" onclick="qualify()">See if you qualify</button>
</form>
<h4 id="qual"> Look here to check</h4>
```

Comment: This works pretty well, I'm validating it at a later point, thank you